# Manual order status change

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a magento store, in which a customer tried to make an order. 
He has chosen debit card payment. Once he had paid he has closed the window or it may have been a network connectivity issue. However I received the payment. So our warehouse manager shipped the product. But we are unable to make the order as complete. So stock item has also not been updated. Is there anyway to change the order status as `complete`manually

Comment: Is it the order status or state? http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/04/21/magento-order-state-vs-status/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the order in Sales -> Orders, then click the invoice Invoice button and submit the new invoice. After that click the Ship button, and create the shipment. Afterwards the order should be complete.

Comment: One question. Will it update all stock and everything as same as other success order?

Comment: The stock is changed when placing the order by default. So it should be updated indeed. It's possible the payment method has a different behaviour, so if it's still not changed, just update the stock by hand using Catalog -> Manage Products -> Open the involved product(s), then go to the inventory tab and update the QTY to your needs.